# JavaScript code is not working

Tags: javascript

Im trying to control the functionality for the drop down menus, the rules are

- Both boxes cannot be ticked at the same time
- When one box is selected only then should the drop down be editable otherwise it should be read only
- The drop down should become read only when no is ticked
- When one box is ticked the drop down should become editable (does not matter which box is ticked)

The problem is when I tick a box it becomes editable but then when I select the second box it becomes disabled, the drop
down should always be editable as long as a box is ticked as soon as a box is unticked (both boxes must be unticked) only
then should the drop down menu be disabled

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
   if (document.getElementById("1").disabled == false) {
            document.getElementById("10").disabled = true;
            //set default 
            document.getElementById("10").value = "OptionOne" 
            //first drop down 
            document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
            //set default
            document.getElementById("1").value = "ReasonOne"    
        } else {
            document.getElementById("1").disabled = false;
        }

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var previousCheckId;

     function toggle(chkBox) {
         if (chkBox.checked) {
              if (previousCheckId) {
                   document.getElementById(previousCheckId).checked = false;
              }
              previousCheckId = chkBox.getAttribute('id');
         }
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox100" onClick="myFunction();toggle(this);"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox121" onClick="myFunction();toggle(this);"/>
    <select  disabled id="1"  >
                <option value="OptionOne">First Option</option>
                <option value="OptionTwo">Second Option</option>
    </select>

    <select  disabled id="10"  >
                <option value="ReasonOne">First Option</option>
                <option value="ReasonTwo">SecondOption</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make the question title a little more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like that or do you want each box separately?
Your question is badly described. But as an extra info: If you want to read checkbox value, you should get the checkbox value, not monitor the state of option menu!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById("chkBox100").checked) {
        //first drop down 
        document.getElementById("1").disabled = false;
        //set default
        document.getElementById("1").value = "ReasonOne"    
    } else {
        document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
    }

if (document.getElementById("chkBox121").checked) {
        //second drop down 
        document.getElementById("10").disabled = false;
        //set default
        document.getElementById("10").value = "ReasonOne"    
    } else {
        document.getElementById("10").disabled = true;
    }

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function toggle1() {
    if (document.getElementById("chkBox100").checked) {
        document.getElementById("chkBox121").checked = false;
    }

 }
      function toggle2() {
    if (document.getElementById("chkBox121").checked) {
        document.getElementById("chkBox100").checked = false;
    }

 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox100" onClick="toggle1();myFunction();"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox121" onClick="toggle2();myFunction();"/>
<select  disabled id="1"  >
            <option value="OptionOne">First Option</option>
            <option value="OptionTwo">Second Option</option>
</select>

<select  disabled id="10"  >
            <option value="ReasonOne">First Option</option>
            <option value="ReasonTwo">SecondOption</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the reason for someone to use checkboxes is, that you can disable both option boxes and send custom values. With radio buttons, you always have ONE of the buttons selected and you have to make a decision from option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById("chkBox100").checked){
        document.getElementById("1").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("10").value = "ReasonOne";
        document.getElementById("10").disabled = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("chkBox121").checked){
        document.getElementById("10").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("1").value = "OptionOne";
        document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="radioButtons">
        <input type="radio" name="buttons" id="chkBox100" onClick="myFunction();"/>
        <input type="radio" name="buttons" id="chkBox121" onClick="myFunction();"/>
    </form>
    <select  disabled id="1"  >
        <option value="OptionOne">First Option</option>
        <option value="OptionTwo">Second Option</option>
    </select>

    <select  disabled id="10"  >
        <option value="ReasonOne">First Option</option>
        <option value="ReasonTwo">SecondOption</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: The code above works as you intended.  I used radio buttons instead of checkboxes, cause, well, this is the kind of thing they're meant for.  Only one radio button can be selected at a time.  And we have just one function that is called everytime either radio button is selected, which simply checks to see which radio button is selected, and applies some rules based on that.

Comment: Let me know if you have a question, and please don't forget to accept answer if this answers your question.